# connect to mysql database python3.9

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am using a conda virtual environment with Python version 3.9 on macOS.

I am trying to connect to a mysql db like this:

```
import MySQLdb

# Connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(
  host="jgsahkjrds.amazonaws.com",
  user="admin",
  password="Jabc!",
)

cursor = db.cursor()

# Execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT * from z3")

# Commit your changes if writing
# In this case, we are only reading data
# db.commit()

# Get the number of rows in the resultset
numrows = cursor.rowcount

# Get and display one row at a time
for x in range(0, numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row[0])

# Close the connection
db.close()
```

Running the code gives me this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'MySQLdb'

When I try to do `pip install MySQLdb`, I get this:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from
> versions: none)
>  ERROR: No matching distribution found for MySQLdb

What are other ways I can connect to my db?

Comment: The pip installation is `pip install MySQL-python`. Ref: https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/

Comment: already tried that but I get ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python (from versions: 1.2.3b1, 1.2.3b2, 1.2.3rc1, 1.2.3, 1.2.4b1, 1.2.4b2, 1.2.4b3, 1.2.4b4, 1.2.4b5, 1.2.4rc1, 1.2.4, 1.2.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MySQL-python```@VítorCézar

Answer (score 0):

This [site](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connecting-to-mysql-using-python) has the answer you're looking for. You'll need mysqlclient, mysql-connector-python and PyMySQL.